# If I mark my question as "truly sadistic" for being impossible should I offer a bounty?

Tags: discussion

I have already said that there are some movie and tv questions that only I could  answer; because I was there when the movie was being made I know some things that only a handful of people in the world could answer.

So if I asked something that hard should I at least offer a bounty as a reward for the extremely unlikely prospect of anyone answering it?

Comment: different option, if you know the answer to some question, you can answer your own question, help people understand something and maybe encourage them to see the movie while admiring your knowledge

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, marking it as "truly sadistic" is **Noise** and irrelevant to the greater question and so should be excluded and/or removed.

### As for offering a bounty, that is a personal decision.

A bounty is an "Advertising Fee" and nothing more. It *might* garner more attention to the question and so gain more eyes on it but whether it makes the question more answerable is highly debatable.